# Rectangle's MouseArea.onClicked on first mouse click state property empty

Tags: qml

I have following QML `Rectangle`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle
{
    id: uePlaceSwitcher

    property string ueParamUserImage
    property string ueParamUserName
    property string ueParamPlaceName

    signal ueSignalPlaceSwitcherReleased
    signal ueSignalPlaceSwitcherPressed

    radius: 16
    border.color: "#4682b4"
    border.width: 1
    antialiasing: true

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    Layout.minimumWidth: 128
    Layout.preferredWidth: 384
    Layout.maximumWidth: 384

    enabled: false

    gradient: Gradient
    {
        GradientStop
        {
            id: uePlaceSwitcherGradientPosition0

            position: 0
            color: "#000000"

            ParallelAnimation on color
            {
                id: uePlaceSwitcherReleasedAnimation

                loops: 1
                running: false

                ColorAnimation
                {
                    from: "#4682b4"
                    to: "#000000"
                    duration: 100
                }   // ColorAnimation
            }   // ParallelAnimation

            ParallelAnimation on color
            {
                id: uePlaceSwitcherPressedAnimation

                loops: 1
                running: false

                ColorAnimation
                {
                    from: "#000000"
                    to: "#4682b4"
                    duration: 100
                }   // ColorAnimation
            }   // ParallelAnimation
        }   // GradientStop

        GradientStop
        {
            id: uePlaceSwitcherGradientPosition1

            position: 1
            color: "#ffffff"
        }   // GradientStop
    }   // Gradient

    RowLayout
    {
        id: ueMainLayout

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 8

        spacing: 8

        Image
        {
            id: ueUserImage

            antialiasing: true

            clip: true

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter

            source: ueParamUserImage

            smooth: true

            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

            horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
        }   // Image

        ColumnLayout
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter

            Text
            {
                color: "#ffffff"

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop

                antialiasing: true

                text: ueParamUserName

                font.family: "Courier"
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 16

                clip: true

                textFormat: Text.RichText

                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }   // Text

            Text
            {
                color: "#ffffff"

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignBottom

                antialiasing: true

                text: ueParamPlaceName

                font.family: "Courier"
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 16

                clip: true

                textFormat: Text.RichText

                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }   // Text
        }   // ColumnLayout
    }   // RowLayout

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
            print("onClicked state: "+state)
            if(state==="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased")
            {
                state="uePlaceSwitcherStatePressed"
                uePlaceSwitcherPressedAnimation.running=true
                ueSignalPlaceSwitcherPressed()
            }
            else
            {
                state="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
                uePlaceSwitcherReleasedAnimation.running=true
                ueSignalPlaceSwitcherReleased()
            }   // if
        }   // onClicked
    }   // MouseArea

    states:
    [
        State
        {
            name: "uePlaceSwitcherStatePressed"
        },  // State

        State
        {
            name: "uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
        }   // State
    ]   // states

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        state="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
        enabled=true
        print("Component.onCompleted state: "+state)
    }
}   // Rectangle
```

Now, this `Rectangle` has two states and at the first click `Rectangle` is not in the neither of two states. Here is debug print after first click:

> qml: Component.onCompleted state: uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased
>   qml: onClicked state:

As you can see, state at `onCompleted` is ok, but when I first click `Rectangle`, the state gets emtpy string. Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're changing the state for the `MouseArea`, not the `Rectangle`.

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativestates.html#the-default-state),

> Every Item based component has a state property and a default state.
>   The default state is the empty string ("") and contains all of an
>   item's initial property values.

Without any reference, you're printing the `MouseArea` state in this line:

```
print("onClicked state: "+state)
```

So you should identify the `Rectangle` state using its `id`. In your case: `uePlaceSwitcher.state`.

I've tested the following code and it works fine.

```
    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
            print("onClicked state: " + uePlaceSwitcher.state)
            if(uePlaceSwitcher.state==="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased")
            {
                uePlaceSwitcher.state="uePlaceSwitcherStatePressed"
                uePlaceSwitcherPressedAnimation.running=true
                ueSignalPlaceSwitcherPressed()
            }
            else
            {
                uePlaceSwitcher.state="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
                uePlaceSwitcherReleasedAnimation.running=true
                ueSignalPlaceSwitcherReleased()
            }   // if
        }   // onClicked
    }   // MouseArea

    states:
    [
        State
        {
            name: "uePlaceSwitcherStatePressed"
        },  // State

        State
        {
            name: "uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
        }   // State
    ]   // states

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        state="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
        enabled=true
        print("Component.onCompleted state: "+state)
    }
```

Although in my opinion, we should also use the `id` in `Component.onCompleted` because it makes the code easier to follow. It isn't necessary, though.

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    uePlaceSwitcher.state="uePlaceSwitcherStateReleased"
    enabled=true
    print("Component.onCompleted state: " + uePlaceSwitcher.state)
}
```

Comment: @KernelPanic Great! :) Happy coding! ;)